# How to parse the file from end in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, search

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 8 ]; then
        echo "Usage: sh `basename $0` YYYYMMDD hour min masterid account destination filename forward|backward";
        exit 1;
fi

day=${1}
hour=${2}
min=${3}
masterid=${4}
account=${5}
destination=${6}
file=${7}
if [ "${8}" == "backward" ]; then
        backward="true";
fi

if [ "${backward}" != "true" ]; then
        awk -v day=${day} -v hour=${hour} -v min=${min} -v masterid=${masterid} -v account=${account} -v destination=${destination} -f /var/tmp/selfCross.awk /koba/c/dumper/${file}
else
        tac "/koba/c/dumper/${file}" | awk -v day=${day} -v hour=${hour} -v min=${min} -v masterid=${masterid} -v account=${account} -v destination=${destination} -f /var/tmp/selfCross.awk
fi
```

if backward != true, it is working fine. But, tac is somehow not working what should I do? It is returning immediately. What am I doing wrong in the above script?

Comment: Does `tac`, the binary, prints the reverse of the file on shell prompt? Are you sure the column positions would not change when the file is catenated reversely for awk to parse correctly.

Comment: My bad, it is working fine. sorry all, about the trouble.

Comment: ok. What was the problem with the code in the question and what was the fix. Perhaps, you should just write your own answer in the answer field. Admins here will have the question closed thereafter.

Comment: awk script doesn't handle scenarios when file is sent in reverse, fixed it and it worked fine.
Also, it is saying you can self-answer in 7 hours. I will do that later.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you forgot to quote `${file}` in the `awk` line.

Comment: @Kevin if we do tac and pipe it to awk, we don't need to pass the file as an argument to awk.

Comment: @srikanthradix it's quoted there anyway, look at the line above that, `if [ "${backward}" != "true" ]; then
        awk -v day=${day} -v hour=${hour} -v min=${min} -v masterid=${masterid} -v account=${account} -v destination=${destination} -f /var/tmp/selfCross.awk /koba/c/dumper/${file}` <-- that should be quoted.

Comment: @Kevin I am not sure whether it `should` be quoted, because it seems to be working fine. May be it can be considered a `better practise` because in certain scenarios it might not work. But, it `works` in the aforementioned script `without any quotes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not an answer, but a tip: use "true" and "false" commands instead of testing for string equality:

```
backwards=false
if [[ some condition ]]; then backwards=true; fi

if $backwards; then
  do something
else
  do something else
fi
```